# Printing out Panel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms

Again, I am asking a question about a USB Printer. This time however, the issue is more on the programming end of the spectrum.

I have a windows forms application in which I generate a receipt, which is then supposed to be sent to the printer. The Following things work: Generating the receipt, Sending the data to the printer.

The data however is only an empty strip of paper. I have the feeling that the Software is ignoring the Panel contents and just sends the empty panel to the printer.

The Sourcecode is as follows:

```
namespace MakeyMakey
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void Gridsettings()
        {
            GVReceipt.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
            GVReceipt.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            GVReceipt.ColumnCount = 3;

            GVReceipt.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            GVReceipt.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;

        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pCompanyImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            Bitmap Logo = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:/Users/manue/source/repos/MakeyMakey/MakeyMakey/logo.png"));
            pCompanyImage.Image = MakeBW(Logo);
            QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("Hier kann so gut wie alles stehen", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
            Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
            pQRCode.Image = qrCodeImage;
            panel1.Height = GVProduct.Height + 220;
            GVReceipt.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
            GVReceipt.Columns.Add("QTY", "QTY");
            GVReceipt.Columns.Add("Price", "Price");
            GVReceipt.Columns[0].Width = 50;
            GVReceipt.Columns[1].Width = 15;
            GVReceipt.Columns[2].Width = 50;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] row = new string[] {txtName.Text, txtQty.Text, txtPrice.Text };
            GVReceipt.Rows.Add(row);
            GVProduct.Rows.Add(row);
            Gridsettings();
            Calc();
            txtName.Clear();
            txtQty.Clear();
            txtPrice.Clear();
            txtName.Focus();
        }

        private void GVResize()
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(GVReceipt.Height.ToString());
            GVReceipt.Height = GVReceipt.ColumnHeadersHeight + GVReceipt.RowCount * GVReceipt.Rows[0].Height;
            //MessageBox.Show(GVReceipt.Height.ToString());
            panel1.Height += GVReceipt.Rows[0].Height;
            //MessageBox.Show(panel1.Height.ToString());
            GVReceipt.ClearSelection();
            Refresh();
        }

        private void GVReceipt_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GVReceipt_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Height = 389;
        }
        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public Bitmap MakeBW(Bitmap Map)
        {
            Bitmap newbmp = new Bitmap(Map.Width, Map.Height); // New image

            for (int row = 0; row < Map.Width; row++) // Indicates row number

            {

                for (int column = 0; column < Map.Height; column++) // Indicate column number

                {

                    var colorValue = Map.GetPixel(row, column); // Get the color pixel

                    var averageValue = ((int)colorValue.R + (int)colorValue.B + (int)colorValue.G) / 3; // get the average for black and white

                    newbmp.SetPixel(row, column, Color.FromArgb(averageValue, averageValue, averageValue)); // Set the value to new pixel

                }

            }

            return newbmp;

        }
        public void Calc()
        {
            decimal total = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < GVReceipt.RowCount-1; i++)
            {
                total += Convert.ToDecimal(GVReceipt.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(GVReceipt.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("HELLO");
            //MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
            lbltotal.Text = total.ToString() + "€";
            Refresh();
            GVResize();
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Print(panel1);
        }

        Bitmap MemoryImage;
        PrintDocument printdoc1 = new PrintDocument();
        PrintPreviewDialog previewdlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        public void GetPrintArea(Panel pnl)
        {
            MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
            pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height));
        }
        public void printdoc1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0, 0);
        }
        public void Print(Panel pnl)
        {
            GetPrintArea(pnl);
            printdoc1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Generico";
            printdoc1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            previewdlg.Document = printdoc1;
            previewdlg.ShowDialog();
            printdoc1.Print();
        }

        private void btnPrinter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();

            GVProduct.Rows.Clear();
            GVReceipt.Rows.Clear();

            Calc();
        }

        private void GVReceipt_RowsAdded_1(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            //GVResize();
        }
    }
```

I have also included two images, one shows what the receipt looks like, the other what the print preview generated.

I'd highy appreciate any help on that topic.[image: The displaying of the receipt]

[image: Empty print preview (equals result)]

Comment: I'd try adding a temporary PictureBox to your form and then assigning `MemoryImage` to it after your call to `GetPrintArea()` to see if your Bitmap is getting created correctly.  If it is, then you know it's something to do with the PrintPreviewDialog or the PrintDocument.

Comment: You either aren't showing us a lot of code, or you have not built your `PrintDocument.PrintPage` handler. You need to do that. The idea of printing a WinForm panel to a printer won't work because panels can scroll if the amount of data exceeds the bounds, and printer pages can't do that. Stop and spend the next few days learning how WinForms [`PrintDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=windowsdesktop-3.1) works.

Comment: @DourHighArch I'll do that. It would be amazing if that would be the issue, would save me a lot of trouble. Thank you in advance, I'll let you know if I made it work.

Comment: @DourHighArch I got it to properly render the bon, but now I have another issue. My printer is ignoring the printjob. It pops up for a nanosecond on the q and then vanishes. I've added a custom paper size so it only prints out the contents, but it doesn't do it. If I remove the custom paper size, it shows the area on an A4 sheet, but doesn't print it either, but rather shoots out a bunch of paper. The printer is set as a Generic/Text only printer. Does that have anything to do with that?

Comment: We can't debug code you don't show us. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69555806/edit) to include **only** the code that [shows the problem you are having](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just dumping all your code in the question misleads you and everyone else.

Comment: @DourHighArch I got it solved, there was an issue with the event handler. I have another issue now but that one isn't related to the printobject itself, but rather the resolution. You don't, by any chance, know how to change the printer's dpi in c# ?

Comment: Create a new question where you explain what you think “to change the printer's dpi” means and why you would want to do that.